# Создание списков, количество которых равно количеству элементов введенного списка (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, список, списки

существует ли механизм создания пустых списков, количество которых будет равно введенному числу? Спасибо!

Comment: Списков в списке?

Comment: @gil9red не, отдельных. Например, если ввести 3, создать a1=[], a2=[], a3=[]

Comment: Можно исхитриться: `[globals().update({'a' + str(i + 1): []}) for i in range(3)]`. После станет доступны переменные a1, a2, a3. Кроме `globals()` есть `locals()`

Comment: А как Вы хотите использовать такие списки?

Comment: @MBo сохранять в них результаты лучших исходов бросания кубиков. А вот сколько будет кубиков бросаться - эта штука как раз может меняться

Comment: В таком случае предложенный список списков прекрасно подходит - данные уже будут удобно организованы. Иначе придётся сначала извращённым образом создавать новые переменные, а потом ещё исхитриться к ним обратиться.

Comment: Для сохранения лучших исходов бросания кубиков достаточно одного списка с количеством элементов равным количеству кубиков.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = input()
t = ['a' + str(x) for x in range(1, s + 1 if isinstance(s, int) else int(s) + 1)]
for tt in t:
    globals()[tt] = list()

# s = 4
print a1, a2, a3, a4
# [] [] [] []
```

Comment: Где вводится число для указания количества списков?

Comment: подправил, спасиб

Comment: что-то вот такое выдается
 t = ['a'+str(x) for x in range(1, s+1)]
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: добавил проверку входного числа

Comment: Не проще `int(input())`?

Comment: @EugeneDennis если ввести 4 выводится 3 пустых списка. А вообще круто, спасибо большое!

Answer (score -1):

```
In [28]: foo = lambda n: globals().update({f'a{x}': [] for x in range(1, n+1)})

In [29]: foo(int(input()))
10

In [30]: a9
Out[30]: []

In [31]: a8
Out[31]: []
```

Comment: А за что минус?